# Magento admin page not rendering anything

Tags: blocks, adminhtml, template, view

I'm learning how to create new pages for my custom extension in magento2 admin.

However when i go to that admin page it's blank.

I've got a controller:

```
<?php

namespace ZET3K\Tracker\Controller\Adminhtml\Config;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //Call page factory to render layout and page content
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        //Set the menu which will be active for this page
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('ZET3K_Tracker::config');
        //Set the header title of grid
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Tracker Configuration'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

And a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="ZET3K\Tracker\Block\Adminhtml\Config" template="ZET3K_Tracker::config.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And a block:

```
<?php

namespace ZET3K\Tracker\Block\Adminhtml;

class Config extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return 'heyyyy';
    }
}
```

In the template i try $block->sayHello() but the page is empty. Only has a title. Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change execute method:

```
 public function execute()
    {
        //Call page factory to render layout and page content
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        //Set the menu which will be active for this page
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('ZET3K_Tracker::config');
        //Set the header title of grid
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Tracker Configuration'));

        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the where the issue is. I had 'template' instead of 'templates' as my folder name.